# Preferred Library For Working With Zero Knowledge Proofs

Tags: governance

I have been thinking about a voting mechanism as seen at the following link.
The same text is also posted on the Cardano forum under governance.
https://johnshearing.github.io/bee_democracy/index.html#voting

Implementation will require working with zero knowledge proofs.
Does the Cardano community have a preferred tech stack or library for working with ZKPs?
Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this does not exist in the Cardano suite of things. This is probably why Cardano is giving up to $2 million in prizes with a focus on ZKPs.

https://emurgo.io/hackathon-101-an-introduction-to-zero-knowledge-proofs/

I found this https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs

Which points to Haskel implementations here: https://github.com/sdiehl/bulletproofs

Comment: Amazing resources @PREEB. Much thanks!